# Save data selected into knockout variable from kendoMultiSelect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js, kendo-ui

HTML:

```
<label class="home">Document</label>
                <input id="write"/>
```

JS:

```
var self=this;
    this.elemsel=ko.observableArray([]);
         $('#write').kendoMultiSelect({
                    autoWidth: false,
                    value: self.elemsel,
                    optionLabel: "Select...",
                    dataSource: {
                        data: list
                    }
                 }); 
        console.log(self.elemsel());
```

I wuold like that 'self.elemsel'contained the elements selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Knockout-Kendo](http://kendo-labs.github.io/knockout-kendo/). There is a binding for [MultiSelect](http://kendo-labs.github.io/knockout-kendo/web/MultiSelect.html) as well.

Comment: Can i get the multi selected data without KO-Kendo library?